# Fill dropdownlist when another dropdownlist's value change

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-chosen

In my mvc application I have a view and I have called partial view as below

```
Html.RenderPartial("_RulesSelection", selectedRule);
```

and in partial view '_RulesSelection' I have an used the below code

```
@model string
@{
Layout = null;
}

@Html.RulesListBox(new { @id = "rulesList", @class = "chosen-select", @style = "width:100%" },selectedValues: Model)

<script type="text/javascript">
var config = {
    '.chosen-select': { placeholder_text_multiple: '--All--' },
    '.chosen-select-deselect': { allow_single_deselect: true },
    '.chosen-select-no-single': { disable_search_threshold: 10 },
    '.chosen-select-no-results': { no_results_text: 'Oops, nothing found!'     },
    '.chosen-select-width': { width: "100%" },
}
for (var selector in config) {
    $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
}
$(".chosen").trigger('liszt:updated');
</script>
```

I have used an extension method to fill the dropdownlist in partial view

Now when the page loads, the dropdownlist in partial view loads,
My requirement is to load the dropdownlist when there is a change in first dropdownlist in view by passing first dropdownlist's selected value. how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in Ajax.
You can achieve it with something like this :

```
$(document).on('liszt:updated', '.chosen', function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'my-site/controller/action?selectedValue=' + $('.chosen-select', $this).val()        
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('#secondDropDownContainer').html(data);
    });
});
```

Your controller action should return your partial loaded.